# Replace characters using Regex positive/negative lookahead?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string :

`var a='abc123#xyz123';`

I want to build 2 regexes replace functions which :

1) Replace all characters that **do** have a future `'#'` -  with `'*'`   (not including '#')

so the result should look like :

```
'******#xyz123'
```

2) Replace all characters that **do not** have a future `'#'` -  with `'*'`   (not including '#')

so the result should look like :

```
'abc123#******'
```

What have I tried  :

*[For the positive lookahead :](http://jsbin.com/OcEtAXa/2/edit)*

```
var a='abc123#xyz123';
alert(a.replace(/(.+(?=#))+/ig,'*'));  //*#xyz123 --wrong result since it is greedy...
```

Question :

How can I make my regexes work  as expected ?

Comment: In other words you want to replace all characters by `*` except `#`?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte According to future occurrence/non-occurrence of '#' using regex. yes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**First part using lookahead:**

```
repl = a.replace(/.(?=[^#]*#)/g, "*");
//=> "******#xyz123"
```

**Explanation:**

This regex finds any character that is followed by `#` using lookahead and replaced that with `*`.

**Second part using replace callback:**

```
repla = a.replace(/#(.*)$/, function(m, t) { return m[0] + t.replace(/./g, '*'); } );
//=> abc123#******
```

**Explanation:**

This code finds text after `#`. Inside the callback function is replaces every character with asterisk.

Comment: Can this be elaborated to the non-future version ?

Comment: Yes adding some explanation and 2nd part in few minutes.

Comment: There got to be a pure regex solution for the second part ...:-)

Comment: JS doesn't have lookbehind that's why it is difficult. Other solution is to do that in 2 phases: 1st get the string after `#` and then do the replacement.

Comment: @RoyiNamir: check the update for pure regex based solution of part II

Answer (score 1):

You can use `indexOf` and `substr` for this instead:

```
function maskBeforeAfter(before, str, character, maskCharacter) {
    character = character || '#';
    maskCharacter = maskCharacter || '*';

    var characterPosition = str.indexOf(character);
    if (characterPosition > -1) {
        var mask = '';
        if (before) {
            for (var i = 0; i < characterPosition; i++) {
                mask += maskCharacter;
            }
            return mask + str.substr(characterPosition);
        } else {
            for (var i = 0; i < str.length - characterPosition - 1; i++) {
                mask += maskCharacter;
            }
            return str.substr(0, characterPosition + 1) + mask;
        }
    }
    return str;
}

function maskBefore(str, character, maskCharacter) {
    return maskBeforeAfter(true, str, character, maskCharacter);
}

function maskAfter(str, character, maskCharacter) {
    return maskBeforeAfter(false, str, character, maskCharacter);
}
```

---

```
> var a = 'abc12345#xyz123';

> maskBefore(a);
"********#xyz123"

> maskAfter(a);
"abc12345#******"
```

Comment: @RoyiNamir Yes, it's tagged with Regex. That doesn't mean Regex is the optimal solution and no suggestions are allowed? Unless it's homework/interview questions we're doing for you, I don't see a reason as to why alternatives are a no-no?

Comment: Who said i'm looking for the optimal solution ? maybe i want to know better regex patterns ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir Which is fair enough, but that doesn't make my answer any less useful. You don't have to accept it, but I've posted it for the sole reason of if other people should search for it. How many times have you seen a `how do I search <HTML> with <REGEX>` here on SO? How many times is that actually the best solution (even though they've tagged it `HTML` and `REGEX`?)

Comment: Your solution is well accepted. ( for those who don't want to use regex).

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on a simple regex:

The first one is already answered. The second can be written similarly:

```
a.replace(/[^#](?![^#]*#)/g, '*')
```

- `(?![^#]*#)` is a negative lookahead that checks that there *isn't* a pound after the current character.
- `[^#]` also checks that the current character isn't a pound. (we could have also used `/(?![^#]*#)./g`, but it is less pretty.

A positive option is:

```
a.replace(/[^#](?=[^#]*$)/g, '*');
```

- this is very similar to the first one: `(?=[^#]*$)` checks that we have only non-pounds ahead, until the end of the string.

In both of this options, all characters in strings with no pounds will be replaces: `"abcd"` -> `"****"`

Comment: But can i make this simple regex of myne http://jsbin.com/OcEtAXa/8/edit --not greedy ?

Comment: (it's just that if someone had asked me to do it , this is where i would go . and now i'm stuck and i'm trying to make it work via that path of solution of myne.)

Comment: @Royi Namir - Greediness is not really the issue here. `s.replace(r , '*')` replaces **the whole** match of r with **a single** asterisk (`*`). That's just how `replace` works. If you want something else, either match a single character at each step, or replace with a callback (like in anubhava's answer)

Comment: By the way - if you are studying regular expressions you will have more fun if you choose another language, not JavaScript. It's regex flavor is limited, and missing features like look-behinds, named groups, and many others. For a nice example, look at this: http://regex101.com/r/jC2sO5

Comment: Kobi - right ,personally , i prefer knowing how to deal with the existing tools ( and not the extended tools which available only for C# etc...). but in general I agree.